# Different behaviour of \color in "tabular... m" and "tabular... p"

Tags: tables, color

The following MWE :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array,float}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{>{\centering}p{1cm}|}}
        \hline \color{red}A&B&C\tabularnewline \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}}
        \hline \color{blue}A&B&C\tabularnewline \hline
    \end{tabular}

    Some blablah...
\end{document}
```

gives me :

[image]

The blue color continues after the cell, and even after the tabular !

I know that I can basically solve the problem with braces around

```
\color{blue}A
```

but I want to understand why, if I use "m" parameter instead of "p" in tabular, \color has this strange behaviour...
(Otherwise, why, in the first tabular, cells are higher and A in the bottom of his cell ?)

Comment: The good thing about having package co-author is you can blame the other author https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/72

Comment: Got fixed on github, will show up in the next latex2e release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the footnote on page 6 of the `color` package documentation.

You can use `\leavevmode\color...`   to avoid the problem.

If you add `\color` in vertical mode before the paragraph starts then instead of being at the start of the first line the color whatsit node comes *above* the first line. a `p` column aligns on the first item so it aligns on that node not the baseline of the first row of text.

---

You can address the colour leaking by adding explicit `{}` to keep the colour in the cell

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}%[=2016-10-06]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{>{\centering}p{1cm}|}}
        \hline \leavevmode\color{red}A&B&C\tabularnewline \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{|*{3}{>{\centering}m{1cm}|}}
        \hline {\leavevmode\color{blue}A}&B&C\tabularnewline \hline
    \end{tabular}

    Some blablah...
\end{document}
```

But that should not be needed, if you use the previous version of `array` by uncommenting the optional argument then it works without the `{. I'll raise an issue on github about that.

Comment: it should be corrected by now in the LaTeX sources and will show up with the next release.